# Can I reserve indirect resources with Mesos?

Tags: distributed-computing, mesos, job-scheduling

Beside reserving resources to be used directly by my task, I know it's going to have side effects like heavy usage of DB for example, so what I want to do is:

1. Schedule a task
2. My task is a standard java code requires 1GB mem and 1 core, reserve this, sounds fair mesos supports it.
3. **My task is going to be heavy on my DB, so I expect at least 3GB of my DB cluster to be available and 4 cores of my DB available.** - Not sure this can be done with Mesos.

Can (3) be done with mesos? I looked through the documentation and did not understand whether such an indirect resource allocation is possible.

Note 1: I know I could handle the DB resources separately however that is not my use case because in my case I cannot extend or change the database cluster or separate it to multiple clusters, the database is a given.  The only thing I have control over is on the jobs I'm starting, note: a job can start with zero DB needs and after 10 minutes require heavy DB load.  If the job does not pre-reserve these DB resources then after 10 minutes when it requires it and DB is too slow because of other jobs which did not reserve these resources the job might time out.

Note 2: I asked about Mesos as a general resources scheduler, but if any other resources scheduler resolves that it would interesting to know.